# Not being able to locate an element using contains() in xpath

Tags: xpath, firebug

I want to locate the element using Reject from the below:

```
<span ng-click="moderatePost(post,'R')" role="button" tabindex="0">
    <i class="icon-delete-cross f-s-20 show-hide"/i>
    Reject                       
</span>
```

I tried using `//*[contains(text(),'Reject')]` but it could not locate the element. Please advise.

Comment: please improve the html, and check if the element is inside frame/iframe

Answer (score 1):

**contains() -**

- Very useful, when we wanted to search with substring of available text
- Below is the example how to implement:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(@id,'id_of_an_element')]"))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following;

```
 .//span[contains(text(),'Reject')]
 .//*[@ng-click="moderatePost(post,'R')"]
```

I would also suggest you read more on generating xpaths [here](http://learn-automation.com/how-to-write-dynamic-xpath-in-selenium/)

Angularjs applications are usually tricky to automate with native Selenium Webdriver, I would also suggest looking at using [ProtractorJs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) which is a test framework that wraps around Selenium JSON protocol for AngularJS applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use xpath `contains(text(), ...)` in html that's structured like yours.

I was able to get around this in a similar problem by moving the text in the html to be placed before the inner html content (in your case, the `<i>` icon).

```
<span ng-click="moderatePost(post,'R')" role="button" tabindex="0">
    Reject                       
    <i class="icon-delete-cross f-s-20 show-hide"/i>
</span>
```

This should yield you the same results, (CSS can change this!) however, you should now be able to use an xpath selector to find your element again.